# Matching certain number of specific letter in a word

Tags: regex

I am trying to match same ('reference') letter only in a word. For example:

Makaraka

Wasagara

degenerescence

desilicification

odontonosology

There are 4 'a' in the first word, 6 'o' in the last one. How can I match all of then using RE? I tried using backreference,  but I couldn't manage, the last "sample" letter was never matched. Is there a way to specify the number of occurrences for a capturing group? Thanks.

Comment: If you are only interested in the first and last strings, what is the point of the middle ones?

Comment: well, I am trying to match words in which certain letter appears for example 4 or more times.

Comment: which letter? the first one?

Comment: I apologize for the way I ask. I have a list of words. I would like to match all the words which have a letter inside repeated more then 4 times (for example). There are 4 'a' in the first word, so it matches. In "energetics" there are only 3 'e' so it does not.

Comment: @tetris555 did you know that particular character?

Comment: @Avinash Raj No, I don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^.*?(\w)(?=(?:.*?\1){3}).*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tR3cI7/1)

**Explanation:** This regex matches any word character in the input and captures it for back reference `\1` later. Then the lookahead part `(?=(?:.*?\1){3})` ensures that there are at least 3 more occurrences of the captures word character.

Comment: Thanks, now I have to figure out, how does it exactly works :)

Comment: there was one false positive, but changing the RE to : \w*(\w)(?=(?:\w?\1){3}).* gave exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: You're most welcome. If it worked out you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(?:.*a){4,}
```

Just change the `a` for the letter you're searching.